# Statistic distribution of the sum of $n$ random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Assume we have $n$ real variables $x_i$,  where ${i=1,2,\cdots, n}$. They are independent random variables uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. We define the variable $y=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\exp(i 2\pi j/n)}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j}$. The question is to find the p.d.f. of $|y|$, when $n$ is large enough.

I tried to think about the central limit theorem. But it looks this is not a standard form of that. I also tried to derive the pdf by regarding $y$ as the sum of many random variables, which is also hard given the complicated formula. This question also has a clear geometric picture. But I am not sure how to find the statistics from it. I am basically stuck here.

Comment: Could you formalize „Otherwise independent“ (currently it is not exactly clear to me what this means…)

Comment: I have tried to reformulate the question.